# How to show all Listings from same school?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran

```
rails generate scaffold Listing title:string price:integer school:string description:text
```

I also have pages set up for schools (let's say Harvard, for example). How do I display only the Listings with school Harvard on the Harvard page?

Here is the view for my University of Connecticut page:

```
<h1>The University of Connecticut</h1>
<h2>Listings at The University of Connecticut </h2>

<% @listings = Listing.where(school: 'University of Connecticut'.downcase) %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>School</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= listing.title %></td>
    <td><%= listing.price %></td>
    <td><%= listing.school %></td>
    <td><%= listing.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', listing %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(listing) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', listing, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [Active Record query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

```
@listings = Listing.where(school: 'Harvard')
```

for all the listings for Harvard

And iterate through `@listings` for all your individual listings

Though I would consider using an association between listings and schools (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Also, setting @listings is best done in the controller.  Try to keep queries out of the views, when practical.